# Parsing data from bash table with empty fields

Tags: python, pandas, awk

I am currently trying to parse some data from bash tables, and I found strange behavior in parsing data if some columns is empty for example

i have data like this

```
containerName    ipAddress          memoryMB  name       numberOfCpus  status
---------------  ---------------  ----------  -------  --------------  ----------
TEST_VM          192.168.150.111        8192  TEST_VM               4  POWERED_ON
```

and sometimes like this

```
containerName    ipAddress      memoryMB  name                      numberOfCpus  status
---------------  -----------  ----------  ----------------------  --------------  -----------
TEST_VM_second                      3072  TEST_VM_second_renamed               1  POWERED_OFF
```

I tried with python and with bash, but same results, I need data "name" but when I am using bash
for example awk '{print $4}' in first table it prints expected result:

```
name
-------
TEST_VM
```

but in second table in prints:

```
name
----------------------
1
```

same results with python:

```
df_info = pd.read_table(StringIO(table), delim_whitespace=True)
df_info = df_info.drop(0)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
print(df_info['name'], df_info['containerName'])
```

Output:

```
1    TEST_VM
Name: name, dtype: object 1    TEST_VM
Name: containerName, dtype: object

1    1
Name: name, dtype: object 1    TEST_VM_second
Name: containerName, dtype: object
```

Maybe someone knows how to play around if ipaddress is empty field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't parse the file manually, take advantage of [`pandas.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html):

```py
df_info = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(table), skiprows=[1], delim_whitespace=True)
df_info.columns = df_info.columns.str.strip()
```

Output:

```
    containerName    ipAddre  memoryMB                    name  numberOfCpu         tatu
0  TEST_VM_second                 3072  TEST_VM_second_renamed            1  POWERED_OFF
```

Or, to get NaNs:

```
df_info = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(table), skiprows=[1])
```

Output:

```
    containerName  ipAddress  memoryMB                    name  numberOfCpus       status
0  TEST_VM_second        NaN      3072  TEST_VM_second_renamed             1  POWERED_OFF
```

Answer (score 3):

***1st solution:*** With GNU `awk` try following solution, with your shown samples. This will even take care of VMs which have spaces in their names.

```
awk '
FNR>2{
  NF-=2
  match($0,/.*[0-9]{4}[[:space:]]+(.*)$/,arr)
  print arr[1]
}
' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:***  With GNU `grep` with your shown samples please try following. Using regex `^.*?[0-9]{4}\s\K\S+` regex along with `\K` option of GNU `grep` to forget previous match and print only match captured after `\K`. This considers that VM doesn't have spaces in its name.

```
grep -oP '^.*?[0-9]{4}\s+\K\S+'  Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you it helps, but bash is my second choice , bcs whole my program is in python, and i am trying to use less sub processes, maybe you know how I can achieve this in python ?  if not , still thank you :)

Comment: @robotiaga, we can try findall or search functions for it, I need to check more on it, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

> parse some data from bash tables

I encounter term *bash tables* first time, but after investigating your sample data it is what is dubbed *fixed width data* by [The GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Fixed-width-data.html). After you determine width of each column you might inform GNU AWK via `FIELDWIDTHS`, in your case let `file.txt` content be

```
containerName    ipAddress      memoryMB  name                      numberOfCpus  status
---------------  -----------  ----------  ----------------------  --------------  -----------
TEST_VM_second                      3072  TEST_VM_second_renamed               1  POWERED_OFF
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="17 13 12 24 16 11"}{print $4}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
name                    
----------------------  
TEST_VM_second_renamed
```

Disclaimer: this solution assumes you know widths apriori if that does not hold do not use it

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Comment: Table width depends on data length so it is not useable in my case :) but still thx